# Bypass Windows 10 'Untrusted Fonts' settings for a font used in our Website

Tags: apache, fonts, windows-10, aem, akamai

Windows 10 has a [feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise) to block any font outside the `%windir%/Fonts` directory from loading in a browser.

Our entire website (AEM + Apache webserver) uses a proprietary purchased font which is hence blocked in all PC's. Is there any way to bypass this setting so that the font loads seamlessly in all users.

We need to do something from AEM/Apache websrver/Akamai CDN end because any local changes will not be possible for end users to follow.

I didn't find much help online for this.

Comment: Unless the client (browser on windows) blocks/unblocks based on the information sent from the server (apache/cdn), I don't see how you can solve this on the server. From that article it appears, it's a system setting on the client machines with nothing to do with the server.

Comment: Good news! Or, bad news: if you're using proprietary fonts, it's a good bet you either payed for a use-on-the-web license (as a separate webfont license, or baked into the general license), in which case: just use `@font-face` like you would for any other font because you have the right to do so and fonts come with license information baked into them. Just because a site uses it does not confer any rights-of-use. Or: you didn't pay for this type of license, in which case you are violating your font license agreement by trying to use them in web documents anyway. Even if it's on an intranet.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says - ***"By default, this feature is not turned on."*** so i would assume you are facing issues on company issued laptops that have this security feature enabled.

Depending on your fonts licensing you could choose to do following -

- Use user-agent information to detect if the OS is windows 10
- If Windows 10 is detected show an overlay with the link to download and install fonts

Answer (score 1):

To let the font work with this setting, it is to install the font on each machine with the Untrusted font setting turned on and then declare the font with a fallback.
The second option would it be to whitelist the application, in this case, the browser to be whitelisted as explained in the Microsoft website here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/block-untrusted-fonts-in-enterprise

I had a similar issue, with Icomoon, but the concepts would be the same one: install the font in the system and then declare a fallback font.

This might help you in the process:

http://maurizionapoleoni.com/blog/how-to-display-fontawesome-icomoon-and-font-icons-on-a-windows-10-with-blocked-untrusted-fonts/